# html код внутри php функции ?> ... <?php - так можно делать?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть ли какая нибудь разница между следующим кодом
Для примера возьму add_action хук из wordpress

```
function example(){
echo "Text";
}
add_action('action', 'example');
```

И вот этим кодом

```
function example(){
?>
<h1>Text</h1>
<?php
}
add_action('action', 'example');
```

Есть ли какие-нибудь подводные камни в использовании второго вариатна? Или это просто одна из возможностей
Понимаю что вопрос ужасно нубский, но все же хотелось бы узнать чтобы в дальнейшем избежать таких неточностей
Очень удобно использовать второй вариант когда нужно запихнуть много html кода в функцию, да и результат одинаковый, но я не уверен насколько это правильно так делать

Comment: Правильнее использовать шаблонизатор. Как самописным, так и готовым. В дальнейшем поможет сильно.

Answer (score 1):

Это валидная PHP функция:

```
function example(){
    ?>
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <?php
}
```

[Пример работы.](https://3v4l.org/IJ8nV)

Answer (score 1):

Оба способа приемлемы, выдают абсолютно одинаковый результат. Применение определяется удобством написания программы. Когда надо выдать много html кода, используют второй вариант.

Answer (score 0):

> но все же хотелось бы узнать чтобы в дальнейшем избежать таких
>   неточностей

С точки зрения правильности кода - всё OK. А вот с точки зрения любой CMS - абсолютно не верно прописывать контент в файлы.

Answer (score 0):

> *Очень удобно использовать второй вариант когда нужно запихнуть много html кода в функцию*

Если у вас много html кода - генерируйте его с помощью циклов *(разумеется, насколько это возможно)*. Или сохраняйте ваш html код в отдельный файл, который подключайте прямо в тело функции.

Если у вас в пользовательской функции образовалось множество строк кода - задумайтесь над тем, что бы разбить эту функцию на две *(или более)* с целью её сокращения.

Если в вашей функции выполняется два действия - разделите их по отдельности *(например, одна функция пишет текст в файл, другая - читает из файла, и т.п.)* Это так же позволит давать адекватные названия пользовательским функциям.

В принципе, оба ваши варианта не правильны с точки зрения функций, т.к. ни в первом случае:

```
function example(){
    echo "Text";
}
```

ни во втором:

```
function example(){
    ?>
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <?php
}
```

из функции ничего не возвращается. По сути, это не функции *(хотя они и выглядят внешне функциями)*, а процедуры *(поправьте меня, если я где-то ошибся)*. Правильно было бы записать функцию с оператором возврата значения `return`:

```
function example(){
    return "Text";
}
```